# Sympy: Modifying LaTeX output of derivatives

Tags: python, sympy

In Sympy, is it possible to modify the way derivatives of functions are output with latex()? The default is quite cumbersome. This:

```
f = Function("f")(x,t)
print latex(f.diff(x,x))
```

will output

```
\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}  f{\left (x,t \right )}
```

which is quite verbose. If I prefer something like

```
f_{xx}
```

is there a way to force this behavior?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it, but check out the options here: http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html#sympy.printing.latex.latex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subclass the `LatexPrinter` and define your own `_print_Derivative`. [Here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/b50ac8be346940a0537beb6b446dcf733a6bf2ee/sympy/printing/latex.py#L567) is the current implementation.

Maybe something like

```
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy.printing.latex import LatexPrinter
from sympy.core.function import UndefinedFunction

class MyLatexPrinter(LatexPrinter):
    def _print_Derivative(self, expr):
        # Only print the shortened way for functions of symbols
        function, *vars = expr.args
        if not isinstance(type(function), UndefinedFunction) or not all(isinstance(i, Symbol) for i in vars):
            return super()._print_Derivative(expr)
        return r'%s_{%s}' % (self._print(Symbol(function.func.__name__)), ' '.join([self._print(i) for i in vars]))
```

Which works like

```
>>> MyLatexPrinter().doprint(f(x, y).diff(x, y))
'f_{x y}'
>>> MyLatexPrinter().doprint(Derivative(x, x))
'\\frac{d}{d x} x'
```

To use it in the Jupyter notebook, use

```
init_printing(latex_printer=MyLatexPrinter().doprint)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! For python2 support i changed "function, *vars = expr.args" to "function, vars = expr.args[0], expr.args[1:]".

Comment: You would also need to change `super()` to `super(MyLatexPrinter, self)`.

Comment: Huh, it ran in Python2.7 without that last change here.